# jQuery - after adding a value to input box, not consider by filter function

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to add the text element to empty div, ****In case the text element not in the div*** / **not empty text input in the div..***

After I added some value to first input box, it should be create a new element but it's not..

again, in case even though if i add the value and removed that, then i don't want to create new input added in the div... ( it can be focused on the first empty input box even though there is multiple inputs )

here is my try :

```
$("a").on("click", function () {

        var newAssociates = $("#content").find(":input:text");

        var emptyAssociates = newAssociates.filter(function(index) {
            return $.trim ( this.value === "" );
        });

    if ( !emptyAssociates.length ) {        
        $("#content").append( $("<input />"));
    }

} )
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/r8Xtp/)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mofify your `filter` method like this:

```
var emptyAssociates = newAssociates.filter(function(index) {
     return $.trim(this.value) === "";
});
```

Demo: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r8Xtp/1/)

Comment: yes, you are correct, here is another concern, after i add some value to input, i am getting added a new element. still in case i remove the value from the added element, i should not create new element and the first empty element should be focused..can you update for this?